# Duplicate at the time of insertion using core data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am inserting values in database using `core-data` and see that duplicates are also allowed.

I have searched got that i have to fetch the contents first and then match with the current data if not match then insert but it is not seems the feasible solution.

So please give some alternate.

Comment: Why is it not feasible?

Comment: how are you checking the duplicates match ?

Comment: because if i have 100 fields then I have to match all 100 fields and then insert(no PK)

Comment: can you paste your code as how you match your object with core data objects?

Comment: I m matching using string comparison predicate

Comment: Please paste the code as there might be some glitch in the same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239407/is-there-any-way-we-can-restrict-duplicate-entries-in-core-data used same link ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.  Core Data provides an API for managing an object graph.  It also provides the ability to persist the object graph.

The programmer must guarantee uniqueness of objects, if such uniqueness is desired.

The usual approach is to have a key field for each object.  You can then search for an object with the same key-field value.  If such an object is found, you can update the information in that object.  If such an object is not found, you can create a new object.

In any case, you, the programmer, are responsible for guaranteeing uniqueness.  There are many ways to do this.

Most object representations have an inherent key-field.  If your key is the entire object state, then maybe you can add a unique key to the object layout... or use a cryptographic hash of the entire object as a key field.

Comment: may please give me some links to which i can refer or some other solution

Comment: There is no other solution.  You must guarantee uniqueness yourself.  I just went and clicked on the link you posted in your own comment in the original question.  That link has good information once you decide what your key field will be.  None of us can do that... you must do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntityName"];
        [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keyToBeCompared = @"DuplicateString"]];


        NSError *error = nil;

        MyEntityName *objectInstance = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];

        if (objectInstance && !error) {
            NSLog(@"duplicate object  found");
         // Jst update the keyValue
          objectInstance.keyToBeCompared = @"New Updated value"; // This will automatically     update the duplicate value

        }
```